# Variable php title tag doesn't work

Tags: php, post, title

The following code doesn't seem to work and I wonder why?

```
<head>
<?php
$pageTitle = $_POST["title"];
"<title>". $pageTitle."</title>";
?>
</head>
```

I get the following message:

> Notice: Undefined index: title

All I want to do is to set the title of a webpage based on the input of the user.

I forgot to say that I have two pages. One HTML page with a form and one php file. The HTML file has the following form:

```
<form action="executer.php" method="POST">

Titel: <input style="margin-left: 83px" type="text" name="titel"><br><br>
Achtergrondkleur:   <select>
                        <option name="blauw" value="blauw">Blauw</option>
                        <option name="groen" value="groen">Groen</option>
                        <option name="geel" value="geel">Geel</option>
                    </select><br><br>
Lettertype: <input style="margin-left: 50px" type="radio" name="lettertype" value="ari">Arial<br>
            <input style="margin-left: 124px" type="radio" name="lettertype" value="comi">Comic Sans<br>
            <input style="margin-left: 124px" type="radio" name="lettertype" value="timi">Times New Roman<br><br>

Lettergrootte:  <select style="margin-left: 32px">
                    <option name="5" value="5">5</option>
                    <option name="10" value="10">10</option>
                    <option name="15" value="15">15</option>
                </select><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="verzenden" value="Verzenden!">

</form>
```

Comment: Did you post form that contain title element or explicit set that index?

Comment: There's no index named `title` in the POST array. That simple.

Comment: Its not clear your question. Where did `$_POST["name"]` come from? This warning is obviously, don't you think?

Comment: Quite a few things missing here to give a concrete answer. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. You've enough to debug your code. Also make sure your form contains the POST method and a name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I get the following message: Notice: Undefined index: title*

**A:** The element in your form does not have a name attribute.

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="title">
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Plus, make sure your form does indeed have a POST method.

I.e.:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
```

Just for argument's sake, you've a missing `echo` for:

```
"<title>". $pageTitle."</title>";
```

Use `isset()` also:

```
if(isset($_POST["title"])){
    $pageTitle = $_POST["title"];
     echo "<title>". $pageTitle. "</title>";
}
else{
    $pageTitle = "<title>Title for page was not set.</title>";
     echo $pageTitle;
}
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Just got one more question about the error reporting.. The file I am working in has an .php file but it mainly contains html text. So what I do is I use <?php....?> tags along the file because otherwise i have to echo the whole html part. In my case, where can i put the error_reporting? My file starts with:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

Comment: @Mirwais You would do `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>` then `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>` etc. and if you want to put PHP inside HTML, that is fine but just as long as you do `<body><h2>Text</h2><?php echo "More text"; ?></body>` type of thing.

Comment: I got it. You have been of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

did you forget to echo it?

```
<head>
<?php
$pageTitle = $_POST["title"];
echo "<title>". $pageTitle. "</title>";
?>
</head>
```

Comment: It is showing warning : I get the following message: Notice: Undefined index: title.

Comment: But you are right too @ToonSuperLove. He/She forgot to include `echo`.